# swift UICollectionViewCell text is not appearing in UICollectionView with two custom cell

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I'm trying to make a timetable app with UICollectionView.
So I made a two custom cell class, TimeTableCell and TimeTableDescriptionCell.
TimeTableCell has two label to present the subject name and classroom.
TiemTableDescriptionCell is for the first section and the first row, to present the day of the week and the time.
I just simply dragged the UICollectionViewCell in UICollectionView in the storyboard, and designed two cells and connected each of them with TimeTableCell and TimeTableDescriptionCell.
The two cell's identifier is diffrent.

This is my collectionView(collectionView: , cellForItemAtIndexPath: )

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    print("\(indexPath.section), \(indexPath.row)")
    let dayArray = ["", "월", "화", "수", "목", "금"]
    let cell: UICollectionViewCell!
    if indexPath.section == 0 {
        // Day
        cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("TimeTableDescriptionCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TimeTableDescriptionCell
        cell.contentView.layer.borderWidth = 1
        cell.contentView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
        (cell as! TimeTableDescriptionCell).titleLabel!.text = "월"
        return cell
    } else if indexPath.row == 0 {
        // index
        cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("TimeTableDescriptionCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TimeTableDescriptionCell
        cell.contentView.layer.borderWidth = 1
        cell.contentView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
        (cell as! TimeTableDescriptionCell).titleLabel.text = "1"
        return cell
    } else {
        cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TimeTableCell
        if let timeTableElement = self.timeTable[indexPath.section-1][indexPath.row-1] {
            (cell as! TimeTableCell).subjectNameLabel.text = timeTableElement.subjectName
            (cell as! TimeTableCell).subjectNameLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
            (cell as! TimeTableCell).classRoomLabel.text = timeTableElement.classRoom
            (cell as! TimeTableCell).classRoomLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
        } else {
            (cell as! TimeTableCell).subjectNameLabel.text = ""
            (cell as! TimeTableCell).classRoomLabel.text = ""
        }
        cell.contentView.layer.borderWidth = 1
        cell.contentView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
        print("class")
        return cell
    }
    return cell
}
```

and this is my storyboard.

[my storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M05id.png)

When I debugg, the TimeTableCells are showing nice. 
But the TimeTableDescriptionCells are not appearing like this.

[debugg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4oqWk.png)

In the first section and the first row, there should be the day of the week and the time.
How can I fix this?

EDIT:

My other functions of UICollectionViewDataSource is

```
func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    if timeTableData == nil {
        return 0
    }
    return self.timeTable.count+1
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if timeTableData == nil {
        return 0
    }
    return self.timeTable[0].count+1
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didEndDisplayingCell cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if indexPath.section == 0 {
    }
}
```

I wan't to fill the first section with "Mon", "Tue"... and first row with 1,2,3,4,...

Comment: show `noOfSections` and `numberOfItemsInSection`

Comment: Also try to show what output you are trying for.